# ¿Cómo puedo obtener continuamente el valor de la promesa en forma de bucle?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un script para subir archivos a una web, y los datos de MB/s, los MB transferidos y el porcentaje los recibo por una promise dentro de una clase, el problema es que necesito que me lo retorne varias veces en vez de una sola vez. Aquí la parte del script en cuestión:

```
class UploadCatalogo{
  Upload(file, filename, Cookie){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var stat = fs.statSync(file);
      var str = progress({
          length: stat.size,
          time: 100 /* ms */
      });
      
      str.on('progress', function(progress) {
        let speed = new String(new Number(progress.speed/ (1024*1024))).slice(0, 4) + 'MB/s';
        let transferd = progress.transferred / (1024*1024) + 'MB';
        let percentage = Math.round(progress.percentage)+'%'
        //console.log(speed, transferd, percentage)
        resolve({speed, transferd, percentage})
      });
      var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': 'http://catalogobibliotecaelam.sld.cu/index.php?ID=373&P=EditResourceComplete',
        'headers': {
          'Cookie': `PHPSESSID=${Cookie}`
        },
        formData: {
          'TextoPDF': {
            'value': fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(str),
            'options': {
              'filename': filename,
              'contentType': null
            }
          },
          'F_Title': 'Biology, the fundations',
        }
      };
      request(options, function (error, response) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  };
};
```

La parte del cliente por decirlo así, es:

```
uploadCatalogo.Upload(file, filename, Cookie).then((data) => {
  console.log(data.speed, data.transferd, data.percentage)
}).catch((err) => {
  
});
```

Y lo que recibo es:

```
// Output
0.31MB/s 0.3125MB 0%
```

Y necesito recibir es:

```
// Output
0.31MB/s 0.3125MB 0%
0.18MB/s 0.375MB 0%
0.19MB/s 0.4375MB 1%
0.18MB/s 0.5MB 1%
//...
```

Para poder actualizar el mensaje de subida.

Comment: agrega la etiqueta Nodejs ya que statSync() es un metodo de Node. Me lleve la sorpresa al intentar ejecutar el codigo solo con javascript en el navegador ja.

Comment: se me olvidó mencionar que el script es de un bot de telegram corriendo en Nodejs xd

Comment: pero gracias de todas formas, ya hace unos días pude hacer lo que quería :v

Comment: @UserZero pues si ya lo conseguistes no estaría nada mal que lo compartieras con la comunidad agregándolo como respuesta. Así la pregunta no quedaria pendiente eternamente y podría ser útil para los demás.

Comment: a....utilicé un setInterval cada 1 segundo y al llegar al 100% se cancelaba/terminaba

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolví mi problema, utilicé un setInterval() cada 1 segundo y al llegar al 100% se cancelaba/terminaba con clearInterval() (esto dentro del .then() de la promesa)